# Make sure non existing variable doesn't break the code

Tags: php, laravel

I am searching for a code in database, if I find it then I am searching for outcome that is connected to this code, after all im changing statuses of both records and saving them.

The problem is pretty basic, I am not sure how I should validate these variables to make sure they do not break anything when they are empty. I was sure this if statement will do the job but seems like it will not.

```
$code = self::where('h_id', '=', $id)->first();

if($code) {
    $outcome = Outcome::where('code_id', '', $code->id)->first();
}

if($outcome) {
    $code->status = 1;
    $outcome->status = 1;
    $code->save();
    $outcome->save();
}
```

Comment: This also feels like a case that could have been handled a bit better with [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships) :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```php
$code = self::where('h_id', '=', $id)->first();

if(empty($code)) die(); // handle error however you like

$outcome = Outcome::where('code_id', '', $code->id)->first();

if(empty($outcome)) die(); // handle error however you like

$code->status = 1;
$outcome->status = 1;
$code->save();
$outcome->save();
```

You can kill the script off with `die`, assign a default value, or do something completely different depending on what your end goal is.

Comment: I suggest using `is_null()` instead of `empty()`

Comment: Why @Fitzi? According to php docs, empty will return true if the variable is equal to an empty string, array, 0 integer, 0.0 float, false and null. Which makes this code perfectly fine.

Comment: Because it's more explicit. Also there is no need to check for anything else than `null` since `first()` either returns an object or `null` anyway.

Comment: I originally used `isset` but changed it as OP stated they wanted to "not break anything when they are empty".

Answer (score 1):

The explicit way would be to check if the eloquent database request returns `null` as Laravel returns `null` if the given parameters could not be found.

You also don't need to specify the second parameter if you're checking `x = y` which you can do like so.

```
if($code) {
    $outcome = Outcome::where('code_id', $code->id)->first();
}
```

After your outcome, you can simply check

```
if($outcome !== null) {
    $code->status = 1;
    $outcome->status = 1;
    $code->save();
    $outcome->save();
}
```

If the variable does not equal null, the given model with that specific parameters has been found.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is correct, seems like it returns null. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your models are in one-to-one relationship. If so, you can try the below code

```
$data = self::with(['outcome'])->whereHas('outcome')->where('h_id', '=', $id)->first();

if($data){
$data->status = 1;
data->outcome->status = 1;
$data->save();
data->outcome->save();}
```